# CSS: The body font style is not showing in the table

Tags: html, css

The body of my CSS has a font style set using CSS, but it is not showing in the `table`. I then added it into the `table` and it still seems to not want to adopt the font style.

I had a look through some other posts and am still struggling.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    background-image: url('../images/Landscape.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
table {
    margin-top: -446px;
    margin-right: 428px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute, center;
    background-color: #F0F0F0; 
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 3;
} 
td {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #F0F0F0; 
}
```

Comment: could you please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code

Comment: try putting font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; inside td {} and completely deleting the css element table, th, td {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

Comment: @Guy sure gimme a sec

Comment: @Smoggers tried that already

Comment: @Guy here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/j1sjj3xv/2/

Comment: You want the font-family inside the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your issue here is that the font is needed for the placeholders, not the `table` or `inputs` themselves.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;  
}
```

Then for text that is entered into the inputs, just add the style to the input itself.

```
input {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

Worth noting that you can also use `font-family: inherit;` instead of explicitly declaring the font multiple times. This makes it much easier to update if you decide to change fonts.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1sjj3xv/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `font-family` inside your `input` like this :

```
input{
    font-family:inherit;
}
```

and if you want for the button too :

```
button{
    font-family:inherit;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j1sjj3xv/6/)